# The words in the Travel Log

Tags: word, wordplay

This is a Travel Log from a travelling man. Words denoted by numbers 0 to 9

A TRAVEL DIARY LOG

Today: 3456789

Met my friend 456789 after many years. Owns a shop of home stuff like a 34567. Enjoyed talking with her. Met her last at the 3459 concert.

Great place. Nice historic streets with street vendors. Many 79856.  Tried haggling with a vendor named 6712. He was 0812!

0123456789 tomorrow. It is 516789.

9867 now. Log out.

-459012

Can you guess the words in this Log? Longest is 0123456789, a 10 letter one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think it says this:

> A TRAVEL DIARY LOG
>  
>  Today: CHESTER
>  
>  Met my friend HESTER after many years. Owns a shop of home stuff like a CHEST. Enjoyed talking with her. Met her last at the CHER concert.
>  
>  Great place. Nice historic streets with street vendors. Many TREES. Tried haggling with a vendor named STAN. He was MEAN!
>  
>  MANCHESTER tomorrow. It is EASTER.
>  
>  REST now. Log out.
>  
>  -HERMAN

Note that

> two of the digits correspond to the same letter, namely E.

Method of solution:

> After a false start (trying for things ending -DAY) it occurred to me that 6 was probably S because of "Many 79856". This yielded "--S- now. Log out." strongly suggesting REST. After that it was all pretty obvious with e.g. CHESTER and then MANCHESTER standing out.